# Tailwind styling not showing up when sveltekit project is published to GitHub pages

Tags: tailwind-css, github-pages, sveltekit

newbie here. I need some help please. I have published a portfolio project to github pages but none of the styling is being applied. What am I missing? Any help is much appreciated!
Link to project on github pages: https://mollyollyoxenfree.github.io/my-sveltekit-tailwindcss-portfolio/
Link to github repo: https://github.com/mollyollyoxenfree/my-sveltekit-tailwindcss-portfolio

I have tried setting the paths.base in the svelte.config.js file but it is still not correct.

Comment: Questions have to be stand-alone, any links should be entirely optional. So it should contain things like folder/file structure and every relevant configuration (Vite, Svelte, package.json) directly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the JS/CSS files from within `_app` are loaded.
Suspect that `.nojekyll` has to be at the root or that the [`appDir`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#appdir) has to be changed to something not starting with `_`.